# How to handle air pressure circuit with very different setpoint values

Tags: pressure, compressed-air, pneumatic

I'm a hw/sw guy, with a very limited knowledge about pressure/pneumatic circuits.
For my new job I have to design a closed-loop controller to inflate and maintain two chambers with a given pressure. The media is dry air.

Here the design constraints:

- one single air pump (likely a [diaphragm pump](https://www.metzger-technik-shop.de/WebRoot/Store16/Shops/62259315/6310/AC5A/147E/1E48/AFB4/0A0C/6D0C/4BC3/70102502_70102514.jpg))
- the two chambers will *not* be inflated at the same time
- with some electrovalves I can provide flow to each chamber or keep a chamber closed
- chamber A: has to be inflated to 2 bar ±50 mbar
- chamber B: has to be inflated to 10 mbar ±0.1 mbar

Usually, diaphragm pumps are powered by DC motors. I guess I can control *a little* its speed (and therefore the output pressure).

The time needed to inflate the chamber is not critical. Their volumes do not change, to have a rough idea I can estimated them in less than 1 dm³.

Here what I don't understand at the moment:

1. Do I need a pump with *at least* the pressure I need for the target? In other words, given a pump of X bar of output pressure, no matter how much time it will be on, the chamber will reach X bar as well?
2. since I have a very different magnitude of target values, and I don't think I can reduce the speed of the diaphragm pump to 0.5% how can I finely control both loops? I can use a sort of PWM to power the pump, but still the `Ton` is critical with such a low pressure. I'm afraid I need to put inline a "pressure reduced" for chamber B.
3. what is the correct name for such a device? Please note I have a very limited space: I cannot put inside the usual industrial components.

Of course I have pressure sensors of the desired range on both branches to close the loop.

Please, feel free to ask any other information I left out.

Comment: So 1 pump with an output greater than the pressure and combined flow rate, then 2 pressure regulators to get the outputs you need.

Comment: @SolarMike something like these? https://www.aircom.net/uploads/aircomdocs/Katalog/GB/Kapitel%2010/K-2015-10-2-GB.pdf. But I have to find something that accept the available input pressure (say 2 bar) and can regulate down to 10 mbar. Correct?